# find users nearby cordova like facebook nearby

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation, google-nearby

I am working on an android application which can find users nearby. I need help in design that application.

Imagine you are in the street, you connect to the app and will see a gps view
with all other people that have the same app, so i need to see them in my map.

How can i archive this in cordova app?

I am thinking about:

> 1. When I start my application, I use API to find my location.
> 2. I send that location to my server.
> 3. server returns a list of other users nearby.

That can be possible but for that user need to keep open or put app in background for get above task and it will drained all battery.

I need to get functionality that Facebook user for nearby user find. Have you any one help me on this to archive this ?

To be very frank i am confused to what approach i need to be use.

Please guide me.